# Audio Amplifier Transformer Testing

Tags: amplifier, audio, transformer

I have a bass amp with a blown fuse. A continuity test indicates a connection between the ground and the output of the transformer (circled in red and green on the right hand side of the schematic below). Resistance between the transformer ground and outputs (both) was about 0.5 ohms.

Is this an indication of a problem, or is this expected?

[image: AMP Schematic]

The amp is an [Ampeg BA-115](http://www.ampeg.com/manuals/BA-115.PDF)

Comment: That could be DC resistance of the windings due to the thicker wires and fewer turns compared to the primary. So it's normal but can be a blown winding either. It's better to measure the inductance with a LCR meter while the transformer is unconnected. The measurement should be in microHenries or can be even milliHenries.

Comment: @RohatKılıç just to make sure I'm understanding correctly - in a normally functioning transformer, low resistance between the output ground and output lines is expected?

Comment: Yes, but depends on the output power. Because, if the output current is high (say, >1A) the secondary winding will have thicker wires which leads to low DC resistance for the winding. Almost all DIMMs beep (i.e. rate as a "short") on less than 50 Ohms, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not indication of a problem, and low DC resistance of secondary windings is expected.